# getting empty data from api

Tags: json, angular, angular6

I'm trying to get data from an api. Although I'm able to get data from json placeholder api and also from a dummy json data i created, I'm not ablt to fetch from the backend api. When i try to get data from json placeholder, it concoles the data but shows and emty array when i try to fetch it from the backend api. And its not empty either.

> **component.ts**

```
allUsers: UserCreation[];

constructor(private userService: UserCreationService) { }

getUsersFromServices():void{
this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
  (Users)=>{
    this.allUsers=Users;
    console.log(`this.allUsers = ${JSON.stringify(this.allUsers)}`);
  }
)
}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.getUsersFromServices();
}
```

> **service.ts**

```
 constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

 private usersUrl='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

 getUsers():Observable<UserCreation[]>{
 return this.http.get<UserCreation[]>(this.usersUrl).pipe(
  tap(receivedUsers 
  =>console.log(`receivedUsers=${JSON.stringify(receivedUsers)}`)),
  catchError(error=>of([]))
  );
 }
```

[console when fetching json placeholder data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl8bj.png)

[console while fetching  api data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpwlC.png)

Comment: What do you see in network tab of developer console, (request, response)?
Is there any error in console?

Comment: try specifying the type for `Users`: `(Users: UserCreation[])`